# Use Case Diagrams. Combining use cases good or bad practise?

Tags: uml, use-case

If a player could be assigned to a team then the use case would be **Assign Player** but if a player could also be reassigned then would another use case, **Reassign Player**, be created, which could include **Assign Player**?

Or would the single use case of **Assign Player** be enough and just state the assumption that **Assign Player** would handle the event of that player being currently assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends, as always.

However, this might well be worth a use of an `<<includes>>` relation. Re-assigning a player might eventually be more complex and in the end you'll just `Assign player` as usual. Eventually. But as well the re-assignment might be a completely different thing in which case you have two different and independent use cases. Or it's a "don't care of the previous assignment" in which case you have just one single UC `Assign player`.

**Edit** As per Patrick87's comment I add the following:  A UC represents a single added value a system under consideration delivers to one of its actors. Now, an added value is something unique. Finding that is hard, which is why it need business analysts that know their job. I for myself try seeing a UC as something like a unique selling proposition. It's not obvious in most cases. But once you placed the right bubble it feels right. Don't start decomposing it into single "functions". That's a different story and it can only start after all UCs are settled. Only then you start construction scenarios inside each UC to describe the how-to.

And my general recommendation: read Bittner/Spence who really get to the point.

Comment: +1 It might be good to emphasize that this is ultimately a decision that balances generality and abstraction - which favors keeping similar use cases separate - against simplicity and concision - which favors combining use cases that are similar enough. It's basically the same problem as finding the right balances of cohesion and coupling. I think a lot of people go wrong by saying there are no right answers here, when what they mean to say is that there are right answers but that they are much harder to find than wrong ones.

Comment: @Patrick87 I made a final remark. I have a brilliant answer, but the margin is too narrow to write it down (free after Fermat) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what your teams are playing. It could be a game like chess, or a kind of sports like soccer.

So your use case would be something that tells us about the overall goal of your system under construction:

Is it "play soccer game" or "play chess"?

You can decompose that into more fine grained scenarios, as long as you still describe actual goals of your system.

For actual functional decomposition, you should use other diagramtypes, namely activity diagrams, state diagrams and possibly sequence diagrams.

Comment: Nope. You are suggestion functional analysis. That's **not** what use case synthesis is all about!

Comment: No, I am not suggesting functional decomposition. It is syntactically possible, but like I pointed out, it is not good practice.

Comment: "You can decompose that into more fine grained use cases" is definitely the wrong wording if you intend to say something else. Because that describes functional decomposition. And that is wrong, wrong, wrong.

Comment: If it's "fine grained scenarios" that would be ok and I'd retract my down-vote.